# Find an example of an absolutely continuous distribution funtion whose average is itself

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to find an absolutely continuous distribution function $F$ such that for a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_i$ with the aforesaid distribution function, we have: for any $n\in N$
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\text{ has distribution function } F
$$
We know Cauchy distribution is an example. Do we have other examples such that this distribution has finite mean? Or even stronger, the distribution has all finite moments?

Comment: That's not an average; it's a sum.

Comment: If each $X_k$ has Cauchy distribution function $F$ then their sum is Cauchy but not with distribution $F$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution. Cauchy is a unique distribution with this property.